# how can i do replacement of one word with another in the tableview cell texfield in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm searching a word in the tableview, there is textfield named as find that find any text in the tableview and then I want to replace that text with other text in javafx tableview? I already run the code for finding the word but now I want replacement code, can anyone help me this problem?

```
public void onClickSearch(ActionEvent event) {
    String st=srep.getText();
    //sbtn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event1) -> {
    tc_source.setCellFactory((column) -> {

        return new TableCell<File, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText(null);
                    setStyle("");
                }
                else {

                    if (!srep.getText().isEmpty() && item.toLowerCase().contains(srep.getText().toLowerCase())) {
                        Double rowHeight = this.getTableRow().getHeight();
                        setGraphic(buildTextFlow(item ,srep.getText()));
                        setHeight(rowHeight);
                        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                    }
                    else {
                        setText(item);
                        setTextFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK);
                        setStyle("");
                        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                    }


                }

            }

            public TextFlow buildTextFlow(String text, String filter) {
                int filterLength = filter.length();
                if (filterLength == 0) {
                    return new TextFlow(createNormalText(text));
                }                   Font font = Font.font("Italic", 12);
                java.awt.Color color= java.awt.Color.BLUE ;
                TextFlow t = new TextFlow();
                String lowerText = text.toLowerCase();
                filter = filter.toLowerCase();
                int index1 = 0;
                int matchIndex=0;
                while ((matchIndex = lowerText.indexOf(filter, index1)) != -1) {
                    if (index1 != matchIndex) {
                        t.getChildren().add(createNormText(text.substring(index1, matchIndex)));
                    }
                    index1 = matchIndex + filterLength;
                    t.getChildren().add(createText(text.substring(matchIndex, index1), color));
                }
                if (index1 != text.length()) {
                    t.getChildren().add(createNormText(text.substring(index1)));
                }
                return t;
            }
        };
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing a `cellFactory` does not automatically result in the cells of a column being replaced with of the new factory. afaik there is no way of forcing `TableView` to recreate it's cells. The cells returned by your initial `cellFactory` should dynamically change depending on the search text:

```
private final StringProperty searchText = new SimpleStringProperty();
```

#### `TableView` creation/initialisation

```
tc_source.setCellFactory(column ->  new TableCell<File, String>() {
    private final ChangeListener<String> listener = (o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        updateContents(getItem(), newValue);
    };

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        searchText.removeListener(listener);

        if (item == null || empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
        } else {
            updateContents(item, searchText.get());
            searchText.addListener(listener);
        }

    }

    private void updateContents(String item, String search) {
        if (search == null || search.isEmpty() || !item.toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase())) {
            setText(item);
            setTextFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        } else {
            double rowHeight = this.getTableRow().getHeight();
            setGraphic(buildTextFlow(item, search));
            setHeight(rowHeight);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        }
    }

    private TextFlow buildTextFlow(String text, String filter) {
        int filterLength = filter.length();
        if (filterLength == 0) {
            return new TextFlow(createNormalText(text));
        }                   Font font = Font.font("Italic", 12);
        java.awt.Color color= java.awt.Color.BLUE; // why are we using the awt class here?
        TextFlow t = new TextFlow();
        String lowerText = text.toLowerCase();
        filter = filter.toLowerCase();
        int index1 = 0;
        int matchIndex=0;
        while ((matchIndex = lowerText.indexOf(filter, index1)) != -1) {
            if (index1 != matchIndex) {
                t.getChildren().add(createNormText(text.substring(index1, matchIndex)));
            }
            index1 = matchIndex + filterLength;
            t.getChildren().add(createText(text.substring(matchIndex, index1), color));
        }
        if (index1 != text.length()) {
            t.getChildren().add(createNormText(text.substring(index1)));
        }
        return t;
    }
});
```

```
public void onClickSearch(ActionEvent event) {
    searchText.set(srep.getText());
}
```

Note: You should consider reusing the `TextFlow`, since every time you search or scroll far enough the `TextFlow` and all it's children are recreated for every cell in your current code.